# Setup a docker MS build server image

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild

I need a working example of a Dockerfile for creating a .NET build server image.

No matter what I install, I get the following error, when try to build my projects with the container:

> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

My current Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.6.2
MAINTAINER xxx@xxx.com

SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\tools"

WORKDIR C:\tools\

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=845298" -OutFile "winsdksetup.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN .\winsdksetup.exe /q /norestart

# Note: Install .Net 4.5.2
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/2/1/E21644B5-2DF2-47C2-91BD-63C560427900/NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -OutFile "NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN .\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /norestart

# Note: Install .Net 4.6.2
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/4/F942F07D-F26F-4F30-B4E3-EBD54FABA377/NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -OutFile "NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN .\NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /norestart

# Note: Install .Net 4.6 Targeting Pack
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/A/C3A5200B-D33C-47E9-9D70-2F7C65DAAD94/NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -OutFile "NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN .\NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /norestart

RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/3/A637DB94-8BA8-43BB-BA59-A7CF3420CD90/vs_BuildTools.exe" -OutFile "vs_buildtools.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN .\vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --quiet --wait

# Note: Add .NET + ASP.NET
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; ` 
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

# Note: Add NuGet
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe" -OutFile "C:\tools\nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing

# Note: Add NUnit
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/download/3.6.1/NUnit.Console-3.6.1.zip" -OutFile "NUnit.Console-3.6.1.zip" -UseBasicParsing
RUN Expand-Archive "NUnit.Console-3.6.1.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\tools\nunit"

# Note: Add DotNet Core
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/8/E782433E-7737-4E6C-BFBF-290A0A81C3D7/dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.4.zip" -OutFile "dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.4.zip" -UseBasicParsing
RUN Expand-Archive "dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.4.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\tools\dotnet"

# Note: Add to PATH
RUN setx PATH '%PATH%;C:\tools;C:\tools\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
RUN setx MSBuildSDKsPath 'C:\tools\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks'
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dockerfile installs the 4.6 Targeting pack but no targeting pack for 4.5.2.

The files need to be in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2
```

for MSBuild to resolve them correctly

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you need to install all targeting packs. I thought they were backwards compatible.